# Subsets in Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a table in the date, Product Category, Store and Quantity. There are about 100 Product types (Product 1 to Product 100) and 30 store types (Store 1 to Store 30). For each product-store combination I need to prepare a time-series model. Can you please help me with a fast process to prepare these sub-sets of product-store combination. Thanks in advance! Sample data included below.

```
datekey    Product       Store   Quantity
20150320    Product29   Store24  1500000
20150110    Product20   Store17  941266 
20160331    Product29   Store12  770000
20160331    Product20   Store25  130000
20150503    Product84   Store20  97117
20160331    Product20   Store6   13000
20160331    Product29   Store21  200
20160331    Product29   Store28  193
20160331    Product29   Store22  180
20160331    Product20   Store23  171
20160331    Product29   Store9   165
20160331    Product9    Store23  160
20160331    Product29   Store6   139
20160331    Product20   Store17  134

#This what I have tried for one column, but need help for multiple cols
stest <- split(sales, sales$Store, drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: It's hard to help without some specific data and an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @lebelinoz I have added an image of the data. See if it is of help.

Comment: It would be even better if you could use the `dput` command on your data, and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: It is a huge data, the sample data can be extrapolated for different product and store types. I have tried split function ' stest <- split(sales, sales$Store, drop = FALSE)', but I am not able to use combination of product and store type. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Vishal: Nobody has time to create a dataset and then help you solve you question. If you want an answer, explain and give as much information about your question as possible (including dummay data code or data in readable format).

Comment: Understood. Sorry, but somehow I am struggling to upload sample data in readable format :(

Comment: @lebelinoz - See if this is of help now. Thanks!

Comment: You need to split on both store and product, not just store. You also need to describe what you mean by a "time series model".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` and `unite` the two columns

```
df %>% unite(joined, c(Product, Store))

# datekey            joined Quantity
# 1  20150320 Product29_Store24  1500000
# 2  20150110 Product20_Store17   941266
# 3  20160331 Product29_Store12   770000
# 4  20160331 Product20_Store25   130000
# 5  20150503 Product84_Store20    97117
# 6  20160331  Product20_Store6    13000
# 7  20160331 Product29_Store21      200
# 8  20160331 Product29_Store28      193
# 9  20160331 Product29_Store22      180
# 10 20160331 Product20_Store23      171
# 11 20160331  Product29_Store9      165
# 12 20160331  Product9_Store23      160
# 13 20160331  Product29_Store6      139
# 14 20160331 Product20_Store17      134
```

There are 14 distinct Product/Store groups in your sample data.

```
df %>% unite(joined, c(Product, Store)) %>% n_distinct(.$joined)

# [1] 14
```

Run your time-series regression by group (`joined`). Then use `separate` if you need to split them back after your analysis.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. One more follow-up to this, slightly different problem though. Now if I have to aggregate the sales from daily to weekly level as per 'joined', how do you suggest I should do.

Comment: You can cast `datekey` as a proper date type then format in weeks to aggregate your results that way

Comment: @Vishal, to extend on my previous comment. You could create a week column using `df %>% mutate(weekkey = format(datekey, "%Y-W%V"))`. This will give you `2015-W12` in the first row of your sample data, meaning it is the 12th week of the year according to ISO 8601.